# Embedding Python with vs2010

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, msvcr90.dll

I am trying to  embedding Python with vs2010 and python2.7.9,when I import moudles using PyRun_SimpleString("import tables\n") ,It works error with missing MSVCR90.dll which shows below
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAOTw.png)

but when I test  “import tables” in pyhoth IDLE，it is right.

Answer (score 0):

MSVCR90.dll is part of MSVC2008. Your code should work if you install MSVC2008 redistributables on your machine.

Comment: I have installed MSVC2008 redistributables,but the error is still exist.

Comment: Could you give some details. Is your OS 32 bit or 64 bit? Is Python installation 32 bit or 64 bit? Is the redistributables you installed 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: My system is win8.1 64bit,  Python is 2.7.9 32bit, the redistributables  is 32bit, and the program created by vs2010 is 32bit, when I  import the other modules ,they are all right except the tables,and the pytables is tables-3.2.2-cp27-none-win32.whl